# references: Square brackets or superscripts for Scientific Reports submission

Tags: formatting

In

https://www.nature.com/srep/author-instructions/submission-guidelines#manuscript

Nature states:

> References
>
> We don’t copy edit your references. Therefore, it’s essential you
> format them correctly, as they will be linked electronically to
> external databases where possible. At Scientific Reports, we use the
> standard Nature referencing style. So, when formatting your
> references, make sure they:
>
> ```
> Run sequentially (and are always numerical).
> Sit within square brackets.
> ```

**...**

But then in the published Scientific Reports articles they use superscripts for references.

***My question is: which should be used in a manuscript submission?***

Comment: Seems pretty clear what they want for the submission. Likely they take care of formatting properly for publication.